# What is Hardware Breakpoint and when we need to use it?

Tags: breakpoint

In part 5 of the lena151 RE tutorial I saw the Hardware BP.
The explanation he gave was very difficult for me to understand.

Can anyone explain what is a hardware breakpoint and when we need to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer:**

From the user point of view, software breakpoints are *only for instructions,* and you may set them *as many as you want*, while hardware breakpoints are *universal,* but you may use only a few of them (typically 4) at the same time.

**TL,DR;**

The hardware breakpoints are implemented by a special logic circuit *integrated directly in the CPU,* connected to

- the *address bus* on the one side, and
- the special *debug registers* on the other one.

[image]

To set a hardware breakpoint, you fill the debug registers (generally indirectly by your debugger) with this information:

- the (starting) **address**,
- the **length** (byte, word, or double-word),
- the **access mode** to watch for (read, read/write, or instruction execution),
- the **local/global** mode (not used for the decision whether the code execution have to break).

You may do it only for small number of addresses, it's hardware dependent, the common number is 2 to 6 (e.g. for x86 you may set 4 hardware breakpoints: addresses are written to the *debug registers DB0 to DB3*, while other info — for all addresses individually as appropriate bit flags — to the *DB7 register*).

The circuit watches every access to the memory (RAM or ROM) and *compares address, length, and access mode* with values in the debug registers. If they correspond, the circuit sends the Halt signal and the debugger interrupts the execution of the debugged program.

---

So the **differences** between hardware breakpoints (HB) and software ones (SB) are:

1. In the **number of them**:

   - you may set *as many SBs as you wish,* but
   - only *very small number of HBs* (typically 4).
2. In **usability**:

   - SB is set to a *particular instruction* (there is no way to set them for memory access), while
   - HB is set to address ranges and for the desired access mode.
3. In the applicable **type of memory**:

   - SB *writes* into memory (the `INT 3` instruction in the place of the first byte of the watched instruction), so *it is not capable to set a breakpoint for instruction in read-only memory (ROM),* while
   - HB don't write anything into memory, so it has not such a limitation.
4. In the **speed** (hardware is always faster than software, so HB is faster than SB).

For example, if you know the address of some string in memory and you are interested *when* it will be read, SB doesn't help you, but HW does.

---

Some references:

- [Debug registers for x86](https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86-64#DR0_-_DR3)
- [Debug Registers on Intel x86 Processor Architecture (with or without VT-x)](https://hypervsir.blogspot.com/2014/09/debug-registers-on-intel-x86-processor.html)
- [x86 architecture debug registers](https://www.sandpile.org/x86/drx.htm)

Comment: In actual practice of applying dynamic analysis on code with a debugger, the difference that really is significant is that software breakpoints can be overwritten (and modify contents of program memory). This is especially important if you are dealing with self -modifying code or code that writes to the executable sections of memory (ie unpackers) For example if you know OEP is at address X and you want to run till you hit that address from EP, you need to use a hw breakpoint because the unpacking stub will overwrite your int3 breakpoint at oep. Other more complex nuances as well.